# How to get my proper IP Address in Kali virtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox

**HELP PLS** I have installed Kali Linux in virtual-box on my windows 7 PC and I cannot use any of the tools like metasploit or armitage because of the IP that I keep getting which is the virtual Box IP Address Ive tried to bridge the network instead of the default NAT settings but it doesn't work PLS HELP??

Answer (score 0):

Basically bridged connection means your Kali box will either get IP address assigned by the same DHCP server as your windows host, or you have to assign the address manually and then test if from Kali you can ping your windows host box, then perhaps the router that your windows box should also be able to ping. If you need more information you need to be more specific, I'm afraid.